# jQuery fade in box with unique content

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am making an info screen, and for that, it needs to show reviews from their customers pulled from Trustpilot.
I got the reviews and everything formatted in HTML showing the 20 latest, but I want to present it very sweet. I am not a JavaScript guru, but I thought i would do it using jQuery and its fadein function.

What is want, is have 20 unique divs fading in with X milliseconds difference popping randomly up. By unique I mean, that each div must have unique content. And by randomly popping up, I mean that if box 1 spawns first, then the next should be 5, then 14 etc, and then another cycle the next time around.
Just like what I made here;

```
$(function() {
  var box = $('.box');
  var delay = 100;

  for (i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
    setTimeout(function() {
      var new_box = box.clone();
      $('.container').append(new_box);
      new_box.fadeIn();
     }, delay);

    delay += 500; // Delay the next box by an extra 500ms
  }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CCawh/5/

Is this even possible, and how would this be done?
I am very new to JavaScript, so please bear with me if I ask to much

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:

The HTML i want to spawn will all be wrapped in divs, so it would go like this;

```
<div id="one">content</div>
<div id="two">content</div>
<div id="three">content</div>
<div id="four">content</div>
etc.
```

Comment: Can you provide some of the content that you'd expect to be random? Do you want all of the boxes to stay open, or just one at a time?

Comment: All the content will be wrapped in a div, I want all the boxes to stay. And then the thought is once all are loaded, and after X amount of seconds to reload the site so the boxes start spawning again. I have edited the OP with some HTML idea of what I want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Made up a nice function for you. I believe this may be what you are looking for

Here's a rundown of how it works :

1. Populate an array with numbers randomly generated 1-10 in this case.
2. Run through that array with a set interval, and when everything has
   been added stop the interval

pretty straightforward from there. Set the visibility etc. You should be able to change up the function to dynamically add HTML elements and what-not, but just giving you something to start with.

```
var usedNum = [];
var i, j, y;

i = 0;

for(y = 0; y < 10; y++){
    var x = Math.floor((Math.random() * 10) + 1);

    if(!isUsed(x)) usedNum.push(x);
    else y--;
}

var showInterval = setInterval ( function(){
    if(i == 10){
        clearInterval(showInterval);
    }

    $(".container div[data-line='" + usedNum[i] + "']").css({opacity: 0.0, visibility: "visible"}).animate({opacity: 1.0});

    i++;

}, 500);

function isUsed(num) {
    var used = false;
    for(j = 0; j < usedNum.length; j++){
        if(usedNum[j] == num){
            used = true;
        }
    }
    return used;
}
```

Demo fiddle : http://jsfiddle.net/xS39F/3/

### Edit:

You can also mess around with the speed of the animation. In this demo (http://jsfiddle.net/adjit/XYU34/1/) I set the speed to `1000` so the next element starts fading in before the last element was done fading in. Makes it look a little smoother.

Comment: @madsobel take a look at my edit. Always glad to help!

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using a `for` loop and `setTimeout`, would `setInterval` work better for what you need? Some HTML might help better understand what you're trying to achieve.

```
$(function() {
  var box = $('.box');
  var delay = 100;

  var interval = setInterval(function() {
      var new_box = box.clone();
      $('.container').append(new_box);
      new_box.fadeIn();
     }, delay);

    delay += 500; // Delay the next box by an extra 500ms
  }, delay);
});
```

Comment: I have edited the OP with some HTML idea of what I want